# What does Alice say to Luther?

Tags: dialogue, luther

Towards the end of S2:E2 of Luther, Alice Morgan has snuck into Luther's apartment. She has asked Luther to run away with her to all the "M" places in the world. He unfortunately has to tell her no for his reasons. Just before she leaves, she kisses him on the cheek and and then says something to him.

What is it she says to him?

Comment: It's not stated in the episode. Do you mean is this revealed later in the series?

Comment: @Paulie_D - Either later revealed, does it say in the scripts, do any of the actors/writers/producers talk about it after the fact ... has anyone turned up the volume so loud they know what Alice says ... doesn't matter to me, just wondering if someone has figured it out somehow.